# Video not played well after update to lollipop android

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, android-video-player, android-videoview

I have collection of videos in my server it play well in all other android device except the device which updated to the lollipop

Issue as follows

It start play and no issue up to 10% or 15 % . After that it stuck there for a while and say's it can't play.

We are using Video view to play video in android devices which encoded by the h.264.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decode your url (using `URLDecoder.decode` method) before parsing it (using `Uri.parse` method), like this code:

```
videoUrl= java.net.URLDecoder.decode(videoUrl, "UTF-8");
Uri video = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
```

This code works for me.